# MySql сортировка от большего количества совпадений к меньшему

Tags: php, mysql

Постараюсь выразиться максимально понятно.

Существует 2 таблицы.
одна с юзерами
другая (разберем на примере конкретного концепта) с сериалами/фильмами.

В таблице юзера задаются любимые жанры.
В таблице сериала\фильма, задаются жанры этого фильма.

Необходимо вывести наиболее подходящие по жанрам фильмы\сериалы, по мере убывания.

Рассматривали вариант с столбцами наименования жанра, типа comedy=1 horror=0 drama= 1 и т.д.
либо как текстовый, для поиска через %search%, куда через запятую вбивались сами жанры. 
Аналогично и в таблице с сериалами.

Как оптимально создать таблицы, и каким запросов реализовать вывод?

Comment: к существующим двум таблицам вам надо добавить еще две таблицы многие-ко-многим "юезр-жанр" и "сериал-жанр", а также саму таблицу жанров. Далее формализовать сам алгоритм подбора, то есть какой принцип определения этого наиболее подходящего фильма по убыванию.

Comment: почему в таком случае не добавить столбцы с жанрами непосредственно в таблице юзеров и сериалах?

Comment: а вы почитайте про реляционные БД и их нормализацию прежде чем пытаться что-то реализовывать, тогда и вопросов не будет таких.

Comment: благодарю за наводку, просто после окончания универа уже года 3-4 в БД не лез, все забыл... да тут жене лабу выполнить потребовалось, пытаюсь что-то вспомнить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вашего описания следует, что оптимальней сделать следующие таблицы:

- пользователи;
- сериалы;
- жанры;
- связь пользователей и жанров;
- связь сериалов и жанров.

Необходимый запрос:

```
SELECT
    s.'название сериала',
    COUNT (ug.'идентификатор жанра')
FROM 'сериалы' s
JOIN 'связь сериалов и жанров' sg ON s.'идентификатор сериала' = sg.'идентификатор сериала'
JOIN 'связь пользователей и жанров' ug ON sg.'идентификатор жанра' = ug.'идентификатор жанра'
WHERE ug.'идентификатор пользователя' = @user_id
GROUP BY s.'название сериала'
ORDER BY COUNT (ug.'идентификатор жанра') DESC
```

Где `@user_id` идентификатор пользователя для которого выполняется запрос.

Comment: разве эта таблица не выдаст единственный подходящий вариант? Плюс не совсем понимаю где будет присваиваться множество жанров которое подходит одному сериалу.

Comment: @ТёмаАлександров запрос выведет все сериалы, у которых есть хотя бы один любимый жанр пользователя. Столбец `COUNT (ug.'идентификатор жанра')` покажет число совпадающих жанров.

Comment: благодарю за пояснение, попробую сегодня накрутить

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример который можно обдумать:

таблица жанров (genre) будет иметь id, title.

связывающая таблица user_genre будет иметь user_id, genre_id, priority.
priority - будет приоритетом для пользователя (допустим комедии нравятся больше чем фантастика и т.п.).

связывающая таблица movie_genre будет иметь movie_id, genre_id.

Тогда запрос на получение названий фильмов для пользователя будет выглядить примерно так:

```
SELECT m.name FROM movie m
JOIN movie_genre mg ON m.id = mg.movie_id 
JOIN user_genre ug ON mg.genre_id = ug.genre_id
WHERE ug.user_id = 1
ORDER BY ug.priority DESC
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю необходимость использования приоритета. Тут планируется делать вывод следующий, к примеру юзер смотрит комедии и боевики.... какой-то фильм имеет сразу 2 жарна, и комедию и боевик... а другой фильм просто боевик... хочу реализовать в php вывод, где сначала выдаст полное совпадение (где присутствует 2 жанра), потом где присутствует только 1 жанр....